# Why the size of wxWidget libs ver. 2.9.1 is much bigger than ver. 2.8.12?

Tags: build, wxwidgets

I build last version of wxWidgets and got a huge libraries sizes, for example in compare with 2.8.12 version:

**MinGW** (UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=release)

```
ver. 2.9.1  libwxmsw29u_core.a   16 840 686 bytes 
            minimal              7 448 383 bytes  
ver. 2.8.12 libwxmsw28u_core.a   8 444 360 bytes 
            minimal              3 108 575 bytes
```

**MSVC-10**

```
ver. 2.9.1  wxmsw29u_core.lib    64 806 104 bytes
            minimal              3 992 576 bytes
ver. 2.8.12 wxmsw28_core.lib     31 135 714 bytes
            minimal              1 187 840 bytes
```

The size grown up over than 2.3 times for MinGW and over than 3.6 times for MSVC-10. 
I [heared](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2009/09/debug-build-changes-in-wx3.html), that 2.9 branch has assertions and some debug info even in release version, so I set DEBUG_FLAG to 0 in config.gcc, in include/msw/setup.h uncommented

```
#ifdef NDEBUG 
 #define wxDEBUG_LEVEL 0 
#else 
 #define wxDEBUG_LEVEL 2 
#endif
```

and used

```
mingw32-make UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 DEBUG_FLAG=0 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=0
```

command to build the library. In make log compiller has -O2 optimization keys and NDEBUG defined, but the size didn't reduce much:

```
libwxmsw29u_core.a 14 555 082 bytes 
minimal 5 856 718
```

What happend with wxWidget in 2.9 branch? Why the size is so huge? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Good question, I am considering switching to 2.9. Would be nice to see some reason as to why it has grown so much.